# How to access port number of a TCP connection (for coding) from a kernel source code?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, tcp

I am trying to write a congestion control algorithm (like TCP cubic, reno) in net/ipv4/ folder. For that, I want to use the established TCP connection port number in the code. How to get a port number from any linux kernel files for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htons((unsigned short int)inet_sk(sk)->inet_sport)` and `htons((unsigned short int)inet_sk(sk)->inet_dport)` to get ports as per Wireshark port.